# Cursor immortal in PHP MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor

I'm using [php MongoDb Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

I need to set cursor as immortal, but I can't find how to set immortal in this lib. Can some one help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the cursor is being created when executing commands or queries on the client. In order to make it immortal just call the immortal method on the cursor after creating the cursor. It is important to do this before iterating through the cursor's results.

See documentation for details:
https://php.net/manual/de/mongocursor.immortal.php

As the cursor will never be removed by the server now you have to ensure to iterate through all results or close the cursor manually (e.g. by invoking reset method on the cursor afaik).
https://php.net/manual/de/mongocursor.reset.php

Sample:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->immortal();

try {
    var_dump($cursor->getNext());
}
catch (MongoCursorException $exception) {
    echo "error code: ".$exception->getCode()."\n";
}

$cursor->reset();
```

Cheers,

David.